# Synthetic type theory for virtual double category and its higher categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, monads, homotopy-type-theory

1. For some monad T on a virtual equipment, the paper *A unified framework for generalized multicategories* by Cruttwell and Shulman (arXiv:[0907.2460](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2460)) proposes the normalized T-monoid.
2. Another paper, by Rijke-Shulman-Spitters, *Modalities in homotopy type theory* ([extended abstract](https://hott-uf.github.io/2017/abstracts/modalities.pdf), pdf) studies higher modalities in homotopy type theory by restricting idempotent monads.

May I know the references to the synthetic type theories for virtual double category and its higher categories ?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean -- in particular, I don't see any connection between your (1) and (2), or any connection between (2) and your question -- but I think the answer is that there is no such thing yet.